# Is it possible to sync iCloud contacts with Thunderbird's address book?

Tags: icloud, data-synchronization, contacts

I would like to keep my iCloud addresses in sync with my Thunderbird address book.  Is there a way to do this directly?

Currently I sync both with my Gmail contacts, but the results are not very reliable.

Comment: I added a new contact to my Thunderbird address book and it showed up in the contacts on my iPad. So maybe it does work.